# Social Sharing plugin on every page

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I have recently been developing a social sharing plugin which sticks to the right side of the page (fixed CSS).

I have been using the hook 'the_content' to display the sidebar, but I'm sure as everyone knows, this shows the sidebar on post, but not category pages/blog feeds.

I have tried using 'the_excerpt' to show the sidebar on the blog feed/category pages, however I feel like there is a much simpler way to reach the same outcome.

This is a great example of what I am aiming for with the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-share-buttons-with-floating-sidebar/

Here is the front end display section of the plugin (which I imagine is where the problem is):

```
function add_social_share_icons($content) {

    $html = "<ul id='social-sidebar'>";

    global $post;

    $url = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $url = esc_url($url);

    if(get_option("social-share-facebook") == 1)
    {
        $html = $html . "<li><a class='fa fa-facebook' target='_blank' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" . $url . "'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>";
    }

    if(get_option("social-share-twitter") == 1)
    {
        $html = $html . "<li><a class='fa fa-twitter' target='_blank' href='https://twitter.com/share?url=" . $url . "'><span>Twitter</a></li>";
    }

    if(get_option("social-share-linkedin") == 1)
    {
        $html = $html . "<li><a class='fa fa-linkedin linkedin' target='_blank' href='http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=" . $url . "'><span>LinkedIn</span></a></li>";
    }

    if(get_option("social-share-google") == 1)
    {
        $html = $html . "<li><a class='fa fa-google gplus' target='_blank' href='https://plus.google.com/share?url=" . $url . "'><span>Google+</span></a></li>";
    }

    if(get_option("social-share-mail") == 1)
    {
        $html = $html . "<li><a class='fa fa-envelope github' href='mailto:?body=" . $url . "'><span>Email</span></a></li>";
    }

    $html = $html . "</ul>";

    return $content =  $html . $content;

}
add_filter("the_content", "add_social_share_icons");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I have tried: `add_action("wp_footer", "add_social_share_icons");` but no luck, I have also checked the footer file, thinking that `wp_footer()` might not be there, but it is definitely including in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to share a link to the "current page" you could always hook it to wp_footer()

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is the goal yeah, still having issues with `wp_footer()` I've updated the question with some progress..

Comment: Isn´t it a no-no to use the same variable name twice in the arguments?

    $url = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $url = esc_url($url);

Comment: Does the plugin work for pages and posts when it´s hooked to the_content?

Comment: Yeah I should probably just stick to esc_url, thanks for pointing that out. And yeah the plugin works with the_content hook but not the_footer or the_head.

Comment: That´s very strange. I would try adding a different function to the footer hook just to see if it works. e.g. <?php
function your_function() {
    echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'your_function' );
?>

If that works, than at least you know that the problem is related to the plugin and not the theme.

Comment: Thanks! Tried adding the echo and it worked, so to get the sidebar working I replaced return with echo and success! the sidebar now appears on every page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you mind marking this as the correct answer as this is solved?